# SharedPreferences not working in a duplicated Android Studio project

Tags: java, android, android-studio, sharedpreferences

I create a sample application where I used shared preferences like this:

```
      SharedPreferences sharedPref = getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                    
      SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();

      editor.putString("data", "This is my data...");

                    editor.apply();
```

And reading the data like this:

```
    SharedPreferences sharedPref = getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    String base_data = sharedPref.getString("data", "");
```

This code worked in the sample application but when I copied and pasted the sample application project files to another project in android studio, SharedPreferences does not seem to work. I have tried everything but it does not work. Please save me from going insane...

In the "duplicate" project base_data variable just returns the default value ("").

Comment: `SharedPreferences sharedPref = getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);` change to `SharedPreferences sharedPref = getPreferences("MyPrefs",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);`

Comment: @AnvarQuvandiqov the getPreferences method only takes in one int argument.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need provide a name to identify the preference file

```
private static final Object MY_PREFS_NAME = "MY_PREFS";

 SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
    editor.putString("data","This is my data...");
    editor.apply();
```

Get data from preference:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE); 
String data = prefs.getString("data", "No data");
```

Or try this class

```
public class PrefManager {

SharedPreferences pref;
SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
Context _context;

// shared pref mode
int PRIVATE_MODE = 0;

// Shared preferences file name
private static final String PREF_NAME = "your_app_name";

private static final String IS_FIRST_TIME_LAUNCH = "IsFirstTimeLaunch";

public PrefManager(Context context) {
    this._context = context;
    pref = _context.getSharedPreferences(PREF_NAME, PRIVATE_MODE);
    editor = pref.edit();
}

public void setBoolean(String PREF_NAME,Boolean val) {
    editor.putBoolean(PREF_NAME, val);
    editor.commit();
}
public void setString(String PREF_NAME,String VAL) {
    editor.putString(PREF_NAME, VAL);
    editor.commit();
}
public void setInt(String PREF_NAME,int VAL) {
    editor.putInt(PREF_NAME, VAL);
    editor.commit();
}
public boolean getBoolean(String PREF_NAME) {
    return pref.getBoolean(PREF_NAME,true);
}
public void remove(String PREF_NAME){
    if(pref.contains(PREF_NAME)){
        editor.remove(PREF_NAME);
        editor.commit();
    }
}
public String getString(String PREF_NAME) {
    if(pref.contains(PREF_NAME)){
        return pref.getString(PREF_NAME,null);
    }
    return  "";
}

public int getInt(String key) {
    return pref.getInt(key,0);
}
```

}

then

```
 PrefManager prefManager = new PrefManager(context);
 prefManager.setString("data","mydata");
 String data = prefManager.getString("data");
```

Comment: If I try to save two strings in memory using this PrefManager class, will they both have the key of PREF_NAME? Does this prefmanager class only work on saving one string?

Comment: `prefManager.setString("data","mydata");` 
here "data" is the key and "mydata" is the value , you can save different value with different key like `prefManager.setString("test","testData");` `prefManager.setString("username","jyotish");
and you can get specific String by their key like
 ` String test = prefManager.getString("test");` 
 `String name = prefManager.getString("username");`

Comment: Still does not work. I think it has something to do with me copying the files from the sample application. I just don't know what is it. I have used sharedpreferences for the past 4 years in my apps and it always works. I don't know what the problem is...

Answer (score 1):

```
public static final String PREFS_GAME ="PLAY";
public static final String GAME_SCORE= "GameScore";
```

//======== Code to save data ===================

```
SharedPreferences sp = getApplicationContext.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_GAME ,Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
sp.edit().putString(GAME_SCORE,"100").commit();
```

//========= Code to get saved/ retrieve data ==============

```
SharedPreferences sp = getApplicationContext.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_GAME ,Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
String sc  = sp.getString(GAME_SCORE,"");
```